# Is Intl.Collator possible in an Expo Managed react native app?

Tags: expo, intl

Do Expo managed react native apps have access to an Intl Collator?
I don't see it in the docs but thought I'd ask.

Looking to use it for sorting like this .

```js
import { createNewSortInstance } from 'fast-sort';

const naturalSort = createNewSortInstance({
  comparer: new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }).compare,
});
```

Comment: Any news on that?

Answer (score 2):

It will be in the next SDK that includes React Native 65.0. See https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/08/17/version-065#whats-new-in-hermes-08 and https://expo.fyi/react-native-releases